# How to stub a configuration for some tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, rspec, mocking, stub

I have `config.iafis_soap_enabled = false` in test.rb file. In some cases I want it to be `true`, how can I stub it?

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26794443/rspec-stubbing-rails-application-config-value-doesnt-work-when-reopening-class

Comment: @AmitPatel How about if I do `Rails.application.config.iafis_soap_enabled = true` in before and `Rails.application.config.iafis_soap_enabled = false` in after blocks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can stub this in a before block:

```rb
before do
  allow(Rails.application.config).to receive(:iafis_soap_enabled).and_return(true)
end
```

Since you are stubbing the method call, you do not need to reset the value to `false` in an after block.